# Create Polygon mapping in R

Tags: r

I want to create a map showing polygon and I am using leaflet maps

I have a data frame containing 10mn records of latitude and longitude of users named Customer. Sample Data

```
CID    Lat      Long  
1    18.951286 72.82392  
1    18.890755 79.44525  
1    18.856558 79.44391  
2    18.951231 72.82388  
2    18.861876 79.46420      
3    18.951185 72.82384
```

I have another data frame containing 0.4mn latitude and longitude of cafes in a country namely Test. Sample data

```
CafeCode    Lat      Long  
1       18.55272  73.88964  
2       18.50029  73.94067  
3       18.74916  79.51071  
4       18.45518  79.12921  
5       18.53899  73.88588   
6       18.70278  73.68761
```

I want to create a polygon for every user which has his lat long from customer data frame and place markers of lat long from Test dataframe inside the polygon of user.

**Output should show how many cafes are inside the polygon of the user**

I tried this code but do not know how to modify this specific to a user and match lat long from Test and create a polygon

```
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  fitBounds(73.92461, 18.57044, 72.82384, 18.951185) %>% 
  addPolygons(c(73.92461,72.82384), 
              c(18.57044,18.951185))
```

Thanks

Comment: Where does the user polygon come from? You only show individual points for each user. Do you want to make one map per user?

Comment: `st_intersection` from the `sf` package will be helpful here.